# Error running SAGA NextGen plugin's "Points to lines" tool

Tags: qgis-processing

I am using QGIS 3.30.1 and am attempting to use the SAGA NextGen plugin to access SAGA processing algorithms, in particular the "convert points to lines" tool. I am using SAGA 7.3.0 installed from Linux Mint repositories. I am getting the following error (see paste below.)

Am I using the wrong version of SAGA?

```
2023-04-12T11:40:06     INFO    SAGA execution commands
             shapes_lines "Convert Points to Line(s)" -POINTS "/home/dto/union.shp" -ORDER "number" -SEPARATE "number" -ELEVATION "fid" -LINES "/tmp/processing_TEYjIo/9a6aab2f70064efb8ebb5349faebffc6/LINES.shp"
2023-04-12T11:40:07     INFO    SAGA execution console output
             ____________________________
             
             ##### ## ##### ##
             ### ### ## ###
             ### # ## ## #### # ##
             ### ##### ## # #####
             ##### # ## ##### # ##
             ____________________________
             
             SAGA Version: 7.3.0
             
             ____________________________
             library path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/saga/
             library name: libshapes_lines
             library : shapes_lines
             tool : Convert Points to Line(s)
             identifier : 1
             author : O.Conrad (c) 2008
             processors : 16 [16]
             ____________________________
             
             Load shapes: /home/dto/union.shp...
             
             
             Error: Points
             
             Usage: saga_cmd shapes_lines 1 [-LINES ] [-POINTS ] [-ORDER ] [-SEPARATE ] [-ELEVATION ]
             -LINES: Lines
             Shapes (output)
             -POINTS: Points
             Shapes (input)
             -ORDER: Order by...
             Table field
             -SEPARATE: Separate by...
             Table field
             -ELEVATION: Elevation
             Table field
```